# How does one characterise the reals without points?

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory, field-theory

The Real number line is defined upto unique isomorphism in the category $Fld$ as a Dedekind complete ordered field.

One can view the Reals geometrically with its usual topology.

In pointless topology one drops the points and simply focuses on the topology itself.

In this situation what would be the equivalent uniqueness statement, presumably in the category of Frames - $Frm$?